# how to set CONF_X86_PTDUMP?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, config, page-tables

I have a 3.19.0-25 generic kernel. I want to see page table of all processes in Linux. So, I was told to set `CONF_X86_PTDUMP`. But I don’t know how to set `CONF_X86_PTDUMP` and the Ubuntu page on [build your own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) was not helpful.
Where do I verify to see if `CONF_X86_PTDUMP` flag is set.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First make sure you are able to build custom kernel as is, and that you can load your Ubuntu with your custom kernel (the link you mentioned should be helpful at this). Once you have it up and running, it's not hard to change some config option and then rebuild your kernel. Just do `make menuconfig` and enable option you want (it should be `CONFIG_X86_PTDUMP`, not `CONF_*`, because all options in kernel are started with `CONFIG_` prefix). Hint: when you are in `menuconfig`, you can search for option of interest by pressing `/` key.

Comment: I tried to build a kernel with 4.1.4 in my virtual machine with was 16GB storage. The building terminated with a low storage warning right now I have only 5MB left. I plan to install now virtual machine with 50GB space.